# Write a single rails active record query to get all the items by association with two tables?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have three tables like vendors, locations, technologies and two association tables like vendor_location, vendor_technology.

The association is as follows

vendor.rb

```
has_many :vendor_technologies
has_many :vendor_locations
has_many :locations, through: :vendor_locations
has_many :technologies, through: :vendor_technologies
```

location.rb

```
has_many :vendor_locations
has_many :vendors, through: :vendor_locations
```

technology.rb

```
has_many :vendor_technologies
has_many :vendors, through: :vendor_technologies
```

vendor_location.rb

```
belongs_to :location
belongs_to :vendor
```

vendor_technology.rb

```
belongs_to :technology
belongs_to :vendor
```

From the above tables, I need,

```
1) vendors in locations (india)
need: list of vendors
2) vendors in technology (php)
need: list of vendors
3) vendors in technology and location (php and india)
need: list of vendors
```

For the above requirement, I need three single queries without using join operation. Because, join takes more memory (vendor table has 12 column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you are maintaining so many tables, we can simply do like this:

```
 #vendor.rb 
   has_many :locations 
   has_many :technologies

#location.rb 
  belongs_to :vendor

#technology.rb
  belongs_to :technology
```

**Now load the vendors list just once:**

```
 @vendors =  Vendor.includes(:locations, :technologies)
```

Now, fetch the required data based on your condition.The great thing here is fetching data based on your condition is not going to fire any extra queries.

```
 @vendors.first.locations.select {|x|  x.place == 'India' }
 @vendors.first.technologies.select {|x|  x.tech_name  == 'PHP' }
```

Comment: Because, 'locations' tables doesn't have vendor_id. as well as technologies table also. Instead we create two other tables called vendor_locations, vendor_technologies (contains vendor_id, location_id/technology_id)

Comment: Then have those columns added to respective tables(vendor_id in technologies table & locations table). That's actually the rails way to do it. 

Still if like to continue with your existing setup, then also my written answer(for using the includes method) will work for you :)

Comment: Thanks.. I tried the include method it work for me.. :)